# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm, speech-recognition, prediction

I am working on speech classification using LSTM. I want to create some methods to predict sounds. However, I receive the following error

```
"ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: 
expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 40]"
```

LSTM Model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))
```

Prediction function:

```
import librosa 
import numpy as np 

def extract_feature(file_name):
   
    try:
        audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast') 
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio_data, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
        mfccsscaled = np.mean(mfccs.T,axis=0)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error encountered while parsing file: ", file)
        return None, None

    return np.array([mfccsscaled])

def print_prediction(file_name):
    prediction_feature = extract_feature(file_name) 

    predicted_vector = model.predict_classes(prediction_feature)
    predicted_class = le.inverse_transform(predicted_vector) 
    print("The predicted class is:", predicted_class[0], '\n') 

    predicted_proba_vector = model.predict_proba(prediction_feature) 
    predicted_proba = predicted_proba_vector[0]
    for i in range(len(predicted_proba)): 
        category = le.inverse_transform(np.array([i]))
        print(category[0], "\t\t : ", format(predicted_proba[i], '.32f') )

filename = 'sound1.wav' 
print(extract_features(file_name).shape)
print_prediction(filename)
```

Does anyone know the reason and the solution?

Comment: I think you might have a bug in your feature extractor, `np.mean` gets rid of your time dimension, and returns a one dimensional array, but your first layer in the Sequential expects some form of data series with size `[batch x  time_steps x features]`.

Comment: thank you for your comment. But I am new in this field and programming. Can you please tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: Try just removing the `np.mean` and just write `mfccsscaled = mfccs.T`. You should think about what kind of scaling you want here, but it should probably keep your time dimension intact if you want to use LSTMs.